# How to use "strongly typed data table" (or "row") in WebForms code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, strongly-typed-dataset

Our asp.net WebForms application is using table-adapters for "strongly typed data tables" and data-rows. In the code-behind I find I cannot use the return value directly from the BLL-class instance (such as our "Main_TblAdap.CostDataTable") as in referring to the strongly-typed data-rows and columns/fields within.

What is the proper way to make use of the strongly-typed data-table or data-row within the code behind events and methods?

Further, we want the ability to reference a specific data-row or sort/filter the data-table.

A good coding example would be very helpful showing the best way to (1) get from a strongly-typed data-table to reference values in a specific data-row from within the data-table and (2) how to sort/filter the strongly-typed data-table.

Answer (score 0):

First create a DataView from the Table. You can either customize the view on initialization or call get default.

```
DataView dv = yourTable.DefaultView;
```

Or go ahead and filter the view from the table when you create your reference pointer like so:

```
DataView custDV = new DataView(YourTable[yourTableName], 
"VehicleID = 'xxx'", // Row filter
"VehicleID", // Sort
DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Now you can sort the View and filter by Row state

```
dv.Sort();
view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.Added | 
    DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;
```

ROWS.
You can interact with the DataRowView IEnumerable within the DataView.

```
 foreach (DataRowView rowView in thisDataView)
 {
   // your code here
 }
```

OR

```
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
     // your code here
    }
```

To find rows in the table try:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Id"] = 4);

    if(result !=null)
    {
        int x = 0;
    }
```

Now just bind to your view and if you add a row or update it, the view gets updated as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However, I do not see the relationship between variables and the examples.  For instance: for sorting, what is 'view' ; is it "dv"? if not, what is "view"?  I am not sure of what is being filtered or sorted?  What if I want to filter by "VehicleID=555"? ALSO, in the "// your code here", are the fields strongly typed as in "r.InitalDate" -- how are the fields referenced?  In the last example what is "dt"? - the strongly typed table "yourTable"?  or what is it?  Thanks.

Comment: You are creating the pointer dv using your table : DataView dv = yourTable.DefaultView; Once you have your dv reference you can interact with it to Sort using dv.Sort(); Which has some overloads. You can also update the data table rows and the view will reflect this.

Comment: Again, thank you for the reply.  You have clarified some of my previous questions.  My one remaining question is : In the ROWS section of your example, how do I reference a specific field of the 'rowView' or 'r' variable within the loops?  I am  asking this to determine if I can reference a field "VehicleYear" from the row-variable such as If (rowView.VehicleYear < 2000) {...} (this implies strongly-typed).  Or do I have to reference it as  rowView["VehicleYear"] ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of your If (rowView.VehicleYear < 2000) {...} are you binding or performing and operation for those specific matches?

Comment: I would be performing operations, with in the DataBound()-event.